# jquery ajax loads page instead of asp.net method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm calling such ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/AjaxHelper.aspx/Method",
       data: "{}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (result) {
       }
    }
```

Codebehind function inside AjaxHelper.aspx:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string Method()
{
   return "some string";
}
```

But it just loads the content of the AjaxHelper.aspx page, it doesn't invoke Method(). Now every ajax method doesn't work on the website.
The file AjaxHelper.aspx lies in the route of the website folder.

Eveything works fine on my local machine and everything worked fine before yesterday production server was upgraded with this patch for UrlRouting: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368

Maybe some other official updates were installed for the Windows Server 2008 x64, I dont know tight now. What do I do to solve the problem of invoking Method() from jquery ajax?

Comment: which version of .net you are using?

Comment: If you remove the patch, does it work again?

Comment: .net 4.0, the pool in IIS 7.0 is ASP.NET 4.0 Classic

Comment: Try change "/AjaxHelper.aspx/Method" to "AjaxHelper.aspx/Method".

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, can't delete it right now, not in the office. will revert the updates if will not find any solution.

Comment: @vladimir77, tried it, didn't help. I tried even to provide full address to the method like this http://www.website.com/AjaxHelper.aspx/Method

Comment: see please: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2520479 [pay attention to 'Resolution']

Comment: @vladimir77, hmm, this seems to be the issue with the patch. Will do the update on the server today and tell if it will work out. thanks so much anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to vladimir77, he pointed out thath it was an official issue with the extensionless url patch I installed.

Here are the solutions:

http://www.shanmcarthur.net/Default.aspx?DN=7d0cd525-bbc5-46c3-8096-95f93827aeea

http://forums.iis.net/p/1176071/1978608.aspx#1978608